# Why does the jQuery UI Content area extend so far down the page?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I added a jQuery UI accordion here: http://www.letmagichappen.com/web_resources to accommodate a large amount of data. The accordion works fine, but the size of the content area is much larger than needed for the content.

I reviewed the css:

```
.web_resources .ui-accordion { width: 100%; }
.web_resources .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header { cursor: pointer; position: relative; margin-top: 1px; zoom: 1; }
.web_resources .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-li-fix { display: inline; }
.web_resources .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header-active { border-bottom: 0 !important; }
.web_resources .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header a { display: block; font-size: 1em; padding: .5em .5em .5em .7em; }
.web_resources .ui-accordion-icons .ui-accordion-header a { padding-left: 2.2em; }
.web_resources .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header .ui-icon { position: absolute; left: .5em; top: 50%; margin-top: -8px; }
.web_resources .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content { padding: 1em 2.2em; border-top: 0; margin-top: -2px; position: relative; top: 1px; margin-bottom: 2px; overflow: auto; display: none; zoom: 1; }
.web_resources .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content-active { display: block; }
```

The HTML is pretty straight forward:

```
<h4>Chapter 1</h4>
<div>
<p><a href="http://www.ajronline.org/content/153/1/87.full.pdf">Rotator Cuff Tears: Prospective Comparison of MR Imaging with Arthrography, Sonography, and Surgery</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.nejm.org/doi/pdf/10.1056/NEJM199407143310201">Magnetic Resonance Imaging of the Lumbar Spine in People without Back Pain</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.ajronline.org/content/147/2/293.full.pdf+html">1.5 Tesla Surface Coil MRI of the Knee</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.yogaresearchsociety.com/">Yoga Research Society</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.rsna.org/">Radiological Society of North America</a></p>
<p><a href="http://www.apple.com">Sample 1</a></p>
</div>
```

Here is the code for the Accordion:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
   $(".web_resources").accordion({ header: "h4" });
});
</script>
```

I would appreciate some insights into what is causing the content area to display so big and how to bring it under control.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was much simpler than I thought. By default Accordion "auto-heights" to the largest div. To change that requires to set it to:

> autoHeight: false